# How to avoid counting the repeated vowel?

Tags: java

I have written the code for the first part, but it counts the number of vowels with repetitions included, but I also want to know how to count the number of vowels without repetitions.

Also I am struggling to write the second part of the code, that is, report the sum of vowels.

Here's what I have written so far:

```
import java.io.*;
public class CountVowel {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter the string:");
        String s = br.readLine();
        int l = s.length();
        char ch;
        int i;
        int count = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < l; i++)
        {
            ch = s.charAt(i);
            if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u')
            {
                count=count+1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The number of vowels are:"+count);
    }
}
```

Comment: The first part looks good. For a beginner for the second part, I would suggest making 5 more variables.

Comment: So, your problem now is how to know if you have already found an `a` or `e` and stop counting it?

Comment: By the way, I would use `String#indexOf(<vowel>)` for each vowel and return the number of hits (index greater or equal than 0).

Comment: Saviour Self can u please explain

Answer (score 3):

Simply, you try with `Set interface` that not stores any duplicates, use following code,

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter the string:");
    String s = br.readLine();
    int l = s.length();
    char ch;
    int i;
    int count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        ch = s.charAt(i);
        if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u') {
            set.add(ch);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("The number of vowels are:" + set.size());

}
```

Comment: Basically the same idea as mine, the choice is to either fill the set or empty it. Emptying it means you don't need to do the if checks inside the loop, but filling it means you don't need to pre-fill it.

Comment: Thanks a lot..It easy to understand and really helped

Answer (score 1):

There is a neater way to do this:

```
Set<Character> vowels = new HashSet<Character>();
vowels.add('a');
vowels.add('e');
vowels.add('i');
vowels.add('o');
vowels.add('u');

for(i=0;i<l;i++) {
    ch=s.charAt(i);
    vowels.remove(ch);
}

System.out.println("The number of vowels are:" + 5-vowels.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to do it like this. This will output the number of vowels as you want without repetition:

```
int count = 0;
boolean[] vowel = {false, false, false, false, false};
char[] vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
for(int i=0;i<l;i++) { //This will traverse every letter for the string
    ch=s.charAt(i);
    for(int j=0; j<5; j++) { //This will search through vowels
        //Ff any vowels are matched the count will increase,
        //But if they are already matched, count will not increase
        if(ch==vowels[j] && !vowel[j]) {
            count++;
            vowel[j] = true;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("The number of vowels are:" + count);
```

Comment: @TimB Tidy enough now? :)

Comment: *I suggest to do this*. Please explain your idea, then show your code. Take into account that there are readers that may not understand the code at first glance, so explaining it would be helpful.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Edited :)

Comment: It's better, but still messy. In particular you're linking vowel and vowels by index rather than either creating an object to pair them or using a data structure designed for it like `Set` or `Map`.

Comment: If you look at the other two answers you can see that we're using the properties of a `Set` to do most of the work for us.

Comment: @TimB *messy* depends on point of view. For me, it's a good approach and uses less resources than a Set, so I like this idea.

Comment: @TimB in fact, you can solve it using `String#indexOf` and avoid using `Set` or any other data structure.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It's not scaleable. It works fine for a small thing like this but if you use it in production code you've created a fragile non-enforceable relationship between two data structures. That sort of thing will introduce bugs sooner or later and it's bad practice.

Comment: @TimB Why use objects when it can be done using a simple linear algorithm. The set will further use a similar algorithm to check for duplicates and stuff.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes, by iterating over the string inside indexOf 5 times, again far from ideal.

Comment: @TimB this will become a long discussion, so to put it short: it just depends. Using a `Set` seems good if you have enough resources and you don't really mind wasting milliseconds, the same won't happen when you write code for a pacemaker, where every byte and millisecond matters. For me, both approaches solves the problem, using `String#indexOf` also does it and it's easier to code and understand. About code flexibility (maintainability, scalability and such) is over complicating the problem, just remember KISS and that this is a very small problem, avoid using a bazooka for killing a fly

Comment: @TimB iterating it 5 times or using 5 checks during a single iteration takes the same time...

Comment: @TimB The problem here is simple, thus requirement should be same for the answer. It's like using a chain saw to slice a simple tomato.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a alternate approach using two `arraylists`. One contains vowels and other one is empty say `charsInString`. We can add into the other one if we encounter an vowel which is not present in the `charsInString`. We can find whether an vowel  has been added by using [`indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object))

```
List<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>(Arrays.asList('a','e','i','o','u'));
List<Character> charsInString = new ArrayList<Character>();
String test = "this is a test string";

for (char a: test.toCharArray()) {
    if (chars.indexOf(a) > -1) {
        if (charsInString.indexOf(a) == -1) {
            charsInString.add(a);
        }
    }
}

System.out.println(charsInString.size());   //answer is 3
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/xR95W2)